# Trying to Add Basemap Background in with GeoPandas, Background is Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm fairly new to Python, so sorry if there's a simple thing I'm missing. I've tried to troubleshoot ):

I'm trying to add basemap to geopandas, here is the code:

```
dropoff = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dataset, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(dataset["dropoff_lon"],dataset["dropoff_lat"]))
dropoff = dropoff.set_crs(epsg=3857, allow_override=True)
ax = dropoff.plot(figsize = (10,10))
ctx.add_basemap(ax, zoom = 0)
```

the image keeps showing as this, it's supposed to display a map of NYC in the background:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the answer.

crs needed to be referenced in the basemap. Like this:

```
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs='EPSG:4326', zoom = 15)
```